# nest js 10 and typeorm 0.3 use own repository in transaction

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem with executing code in transaction using my repository

In typeorm 0.2 I had a piece of code with transaction where I could load custom repository via method

```
getCustomRepository
```

in version 0.3 this method is deprecated and also in nest js

```
@EntityRepository
```

decorator is deprecated

according to docs

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/custom-repository

we should use `withRepository` or`extend` method

```
await connection.transaction(async (manager) => {
   const userRepository = manager.withRepository(UserRepository)     
   await userRepository.createAndSave("Timber", "Saw")     
   const timber = await userRepository.findByName("Timber", "Saw") 
})
```

but withRepository method expect different arguments that specified in docs

Argument of type 'typeof UserRepository' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Repository<any> & Repository<ObjectLiteral>'